# Smalltalk write a Sorted Collection to a file

Tags: collections, smalltalk, fileoutputstream

let's say i have a SortedCollection called `whitepages`, each record containing a `Customer`, with values `name` and `number`. 
I want to create a function which would write them to a file in such way

```
name1 
number1 
name2
number2
```

I have to admit Im completely stuck here. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I hope you know how to write to file.
And as you noticed that you have sorted collection I suppose that `Customer`s are ordered in the way you want.

Then what you can do is:

```
(whitepages collect: [ :customer |
  customer name,
  Character cr asString,
  customer number ]) joinUsing: Character cr
```

This way you'll get a string that you just need to write to the file. Also note that if `name` or `number` are not strings you can use `asString` on them.

The canonical way is to do something like:

```
whitepages do: [ :customer |
  stream
    nextPutAll: customer name;
    cr;
    nextPutAll: customer number;
    cr ]
```

Where `stream` is a write stream to a file.

Comment: I tried to edit your post: spelling nit, white should be write. Apparently, you have to find 6 characters at fault before SO will let you edit it. :)