# How to read/write objects to a file?

Tags: file-io, smalltalk, squeak

I would like to write an object (a simple collection) to a file. I've been looking around and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055357/smalltalk-writing-output-to-a-file) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228668/smalltalk-write-a-sorted-collection-to-a-file). I also went through a lot of sites with broken links etc, but I don't seem to be able to find a way to write to a file in smalltalk. I tried this (and other things, but they come down to the same):

```
out := 'newFile' asFileName writeStream.
d associationsDo: [ :assoc | out 
    nextPutAll: assoc key asString;
    nextPut: $, ;
    nextPutAll: assoc value asString; cr. ]
out close.
```

as suggested in the linked questions, but it does not seem to be doing anything. It does not throw errors, but I don't find any files either.

The only thing I want to do is persist my object (binary or textual does not really matter), so how could I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a write stream on a string. That actually works but the information is stored on a string object, no files will be written.

This works in both Squeak and Pharo (and probably other dialects):

```
FileStream
    forceNewFileNamed: 'filename.ext'
    do: [ :stream |
         d associationsDo: [ :assoc |
             stream
                 ascii; "data is text, not binary"
                 nextPutAll: assoc key asString;
                 nextPut: $, ;
                 nextPutAll: assoc value asString;
                 cr ] ].
```

In Pharo you could write:

```
'filename.ext' asFileReference writeStreamDo: [ :stream |
    ... ].
```

Note however that there are better ways to store structured data in files, e.g. [STON](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~SvenVanCaekenberghe/STON) (Smalltalk Object Notation, Smalltalk version of JSON) or XML. If you want to persist objects than you might want to checkout [Fuel](http://rmod.inria.fr/web/software/Fuel), [StOMP](http://stomp.smalltalk-users.jp) (probably no longer supported) or any of the other object serializers.

Lastly there's also ImageSegment, a VM based object serializer (no extra packages needed), but you'll probably need some help with that.

Comment: StOMP seems to be no longer supported. Latest releases are for Pharo 1.2 and Squeak 4.2.

Comment: Thanks. Il'l leave the link in for documentation anyway.

Comment: And STON is only for Pharo. Fuel does not allow to transfer objects from Pharo to Squeak. Noteworthy is SIXX http://www.mars.dti.ne.jp/~umejava/smalltalk/sixx/index.html

Comment: Fuel does allow object transfer as long as the definitions are equivalent (and you could specify migrations). SIXX is a good addition.

Comment: Are there ways to specify the path to the file?

Comment: Simply specify an absolute path for the the file name, e.g. '/home/you/filename.ext'. Relative paths are always relative to the directory the image resides in.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional Smalltalk serialization format uses the `storeOn:` and `readFrom:` methods. E.g.

```
d1 := {'a'->1. 'b'->2. 'c'->'3'} as: Dictionary.

"store"
FileStream forceNewFileNamed: 'mydict.st' do: [:out | d1 storeOn: out].

"read"
d2 := FileStream oldFileNamed: 'mydict.st' do:  [:in | Object readFrom: in].
```

This is a textual format and gets inefficient for larger data sets. Also, it cannot store cyclical references. For that, check out the more advanced serialization options as listed in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
| d out | 
d := Dictionary new.
d at: 'green' put: 'vert'.
d at: 'blue' put: 'bleu'. 
d at: 'red' put: 'rouge'.
d at: 'white' put: 'blanc'.

out := FileStream fileNamed: 'dict-out.txt'.

d associationsDo: [ :assoc | out 
    nextPutAll: assoc key asString;
    nextPut: $, ;
    nextPutAll: assoc value asString; cr.].
out close.
```

See also:

- http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/1583
- http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/6338

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a syntax for an extension, but not the base.
At least in Pharo, `'newFile' asFileName` is a string, and #writeStream provides you a stream on the same string, not on a file.

Try with `FileStream newFileNamed: 'newFile'` or something like that.

And most of all: when something strange happens, inspect. Inspect partial evaluations and check all your assumptions. Or better yet, debug and see where is the code going.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in Fuel would be

```
FLSerializer serialize: d toFileNamed: 'filename.ext'.
```

And

```
d := FLMaterializer materializeFromFileNamed: 'filename.ext'
```